# How can I customize the window that opens when starting a command from the Windows "Run" command?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, windows-registry, run-dialog

If I start a console-based command (such as cmd or powershell) from the Windows Vista "Run..." command (Windows-R), it opens in a default command window.  I'd like to customize the size, colors, and fonts of this Window.  Is there a way to do it, maybe with a registry hack?

I know I can create shortcuts to specific commands that customize the window.  However, those settings apply only when opening the command from that particular shortcut; in this case I want to open the command via the Run window.

I'm also aware there are various replacements out there for the built-in Run window.  In this case I'd prefer not to involve any third-party software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start up cmd from anywhere and right click on the title bar.  Select "Defaults".  Make the changes to fonts/colors/etc, and hit OK.  These settings will be saved and applied whenever you open a new cmd window (unless they are overridden by a shortcut with specific settings).

Comment: +1 you got there first, and your answer is even more to the point :)